# save a file in java

Tags: java

I am trying to save a file in Java in this way:

```
PrintWriter output = null;
int x=5, y = 6;
try {               
    saveFile = new FileOutputStream("myFile.txt");
    save = new ObjectOutputStream(saveFile);    
    save.writeObject(x + y);
    save.close();                   
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
{               
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) 
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

and it is working but how can I save an object from another class because it is giving me an error when I try to do it.

Comment: can you show that code and the corresponding error please.

Comment: What error is the compiler giving you? Please include a stacktrace and an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org) demonstrating the problem.

Comment: the error is Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at PanelFurniture.actionPerformed(PanelFurniture.java:248)

Comment: and what i changed is  save.writeObject(myChair.toString());

Comment: where myChair is object from another class and the method toString is inside the class

Comment: The probem is that it is really hard to help when there can be a million different things wrong. It would help if u previded all relevant code and your expected result! :)

Comment: It is quite a big project so that is why I am trying to explain it simple but I can see it is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the others say, plenty of things that might be problematic ... However serialization is one way to store a object in a file and read it back to a object from a file.

http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=398